# ubuntu on different phones

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm planning to buy a phone that support the ubuntu platform.Please help me to select one from the list.

1.Asus Zenfone 4 A450CG

2.Lenovo A526

3.Lenovo A390

4.Lenovo A680

which of these provides hassle-free ubuntu experience?
please help me

Comment: I'd wait a bit to get the first Ubuntu phones: See http://developer.ubuntu.com/2014/06/10000-users-of-ubuntu-phone/

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of supported devides [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices).

For each device there is a list of what is working and what is not.
The only phone from your list which is listed there is the `Lenovo A390` as work in progress.

You should look for a different phone which has better support.